# PostgreSQL - Merge two selects queries

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables :

***company*** and  ***users***

the users table:

```
    id   |   name   |   cpf     |   phone_number  | company_id

    1    |   Jonh   | 111.11.11 |   1111-1111     |    1

    2    |   Marie  | 222.22.22 |   2222-2222     | 

    3    |   Paul   | 333.33.33 |   3333-3333     |    3

    4    |   Luna   | 444.44.44 |   4444-4444     |    1

    5    |   Leo    | 555.55.55 |   5555-5555     |
```

the company table:

```
id   |   name       |   cnpj      |   phone_number | company_data | consumer

1    |  companyA    | 111.1111.11 |   1111-1111    |     data1    | true

2    |  companyB    | 222.2222.22 |   2222-2222    |     data2    | true

3    |  companyC    | 333.3333.33 |   3333-3333    |     data3    | false
```

I want to select all the users where `company_id IS NULL` and all the companies
where  `consumer is true`

What I'm trying to do is something like this :

```
 Select u.name as name,
          u.cpf as document,
          u.phone_number as phoneNumber,
          'false' as company
          FROM users u 
          WHERE company_id is NULL

   UNION

   Select c.name as name,
          c.cnpj as document, 
          c.phone_number as phoneNumber,
          c.company_data as companyData
          'true' as company
          FROM company c
          WHERE c.consumer = 'true'

  ORDER BY id
```

And the answer I want is :

```
id   |   name       |   document  |   phone_number  | companyData |  company

1    |  companyA    | 111.1111.11 |   1111-1111     |   data 1    |   true

2    |  companyB    | 222.2222.22 |   2222-2222     |   data 2    |   true

2    |   Marie      | 222.22.22   |   2222-2222     |             |  false

5    |   Leo        | 555.55.55   |   5555-5555     |             |  false
```

I can accept a answer with the columns `cpf` and `cnpj` separed and the results null if it doens't apply to the selected entity. In this way I would not need the `company` column

Comment: Can you share some sample data and the result you're expecting? It's quite hard to understand the question as it's currently worded (for me, at least)

Comment: You're almost doing it right.  You need to actually join the two tables in your FROM clause in the first code snip, and CASE each column off from there, not delegate to two different subselects.

Comment: I edited it a lot now. I think its clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the same number of columns for both selects, simply add a NULL column (you might have to cast it to a datatype):

```
   Select u.name as name,
          u.cpf as document,
          u.phone_number as phoneNumber,
          CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(20)) as companyData,
          'false' as company
          FROM users u 
          WHERE company_id is NULL

   UNION

   Select c.name as name,
          c.cnpj as document, 
          c.phone_number as phoneNumber,
          c.company_data as companyData
          'true' as company
          FROM company c
          WHERE c.consumer = 'true'

  ORDER BY id
```

Comment: Thanks, it works too ! I accepted the other because he answered first. I would upvote this but i can't yet =/

Comment: @GuilhermeRodriguez I did it for you :) !!

Answer (score 1):

Per the above...

```
Select CASE WHEN users.company_id is NULL THEN users.name ELSE company.name ...
  ... FROM users JOIN company ON(users.company_id = company.id)
  ...
```

Comment: tried it but it ignored all the company data. Dont know why

Answer (score 1):

If `users` and `company` have the same columns you can use a union query

```
select u.name, null from users where company_id is null
union
select c.name, c.some_column from users u 
join company c on u.company_id = c.id
```

If they don't have the same columns, you'll have to specify the column names you want to select manually instead of selecting `*`

Comment: I want something like that. The problem is the "company" have more columns and i get the error :
ERROR:  each UNION query must have the same number of columns.
I want that the columns that does not appear in users be null

Comment: Then you have to explicitly select the columns you want and select "null" for the columns that are not in user. See update

Comment: It worked. My problem was that I was doing the selects in a diferent order. The union clause requires that all the data be on the same order. I thought that the alias would do that job.
Thanks for the help!